# Where the in memory cache will be stored? How it is different from storing data in static variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, windows-services

I'm implementing a windows service in C#.Net. I need some of the objects to be cached. What would be the difference if I store them in static variables instead of some other caching mechanisms?

I have my own business strategies of clearing and expiration handling for the objects.

```
public class CustomerConfigurationsContext 
    {
        // Make this to read from cache. instead of reading complete in-memory.
        private static List<CustomerConfigurations> CustomerConfigurations { get; } = new List<CustomerConfigurations>();

    }
```

Please mention the differences, what advantages I would get with either of the approaches.

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Storing some information in (static) variable could be considered a trivial way of caching.

Comment: "what advantages I would get with either of the approaches" We only know the "static" side of this question, but not the other one which you obviously have implemented. So how should we determine any advantage of one over the other if we only know one?

Comment: The main benefit of a cache is the ability to specify expiration (e.g. cache for just 20 minutes) and the ability to react to low memory conditions (memory is low - time to dump the cache to try and get some back). `static` does neither of those OOTB (and building them correctly and in a scalable way is hard). As a general rule, I'd rather use something in a framework rather than roll it myself - but if you are confident in your custom cache implementation, then feel free to use yours instead.